# Background color above UISearchBar - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, background, uisearchbar

When i have UISearchBar and tableView and when i swipe down will show up the color I don't want and i dont know how i can change this color. But only above searchBar.

When i have only tableView all its ok.

When I will call this func bellow is this effect

```
func configureSearchController() {
    definesPresentationContext                                  = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater                       = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder                      = DepartmentsContactsData.searchControllerPlaceholder
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation       = false
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation       = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

Maybe someone knows how to change it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this is hard to figure out what is wrong without any code :/

Comment: I add code - When I will call this func is this effect. When i will not use this func i havent searchBar but i have nice dark color:)